# Cloud function termina con error

Tags: nodejs, google-cloud-functions

Tengo mi siguiente código en una cloud function de google cloud, pero me da error de timeout, y no entiendo por que.

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const dbConfig = {
  user: '',
  password: '',
  host: '',
  port: ,
  database: ''
};

const pool = new Pool(dbConfig);

const joinf = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const connection = pool.connect();
    connection
    .then( client => {
      return client.query(`select * from tabla`);
    })
    .then( data => resolve(data.rows))
    .catch( error => reject(error));
  });
}

exports.guardian1 = (req, res) => {
  joinf().then(function(data){
    res.status(200).send(data)
  })
};
```